# New columns for occasional cases : new columns or separate table or json column

Tags: mysql, database, sharding, entity-attribute-value

We are rewriting an existing system where in the main inventory table, some new columns are being introduced, due to need of these columns in roughly 15-20% of overall cases. This means 80-85% of the time, these columns would be null. These new column data type would include decimal, varchar, smallint.

Now, we have three choices:

- Include new columns as mentioned above, and let 80% of the rows have null values in these columns. This has demerit of null values existing in like 5-6 columns 80% of the time.
- Have separate table for these columns, and join with main table only when these columns are needed. This join will happen only in 20% of the cases, since it will be driven by API request. This approach has demerit of a join.
- Add json column in existing table for fields which don't need to be queried and for queried fields, add separate columns.

I think second option seems most appropriate, but I need opinions according as per your experience

P.S.: The plan is to basically also move this database from single instance to sharded databases. And the sql instance is MySQL.

Comment: My musing on EAV, etc:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav

Answer (score 0):

I will go with `option (2)`. Let's call the main table as `Table A`, the sub table as `Table B`.

Since 80% of the time, the new columns' values are NULL, so `Table A` to `Table B` relation can be `1-to-1` or `1-to-0`. Which means when values are NULL, no record needs to be inserted into `Table B`.

This makes `Table B` relatively small, so the `JOIN` operation shouldn't impose much performance issue.

JSON column can be another option, but there is less strict checking on each field's type within it.